# CORS request from chrome browser

Tags: angularjs, ajax, cors

I have an AngularJs application making AJAX request to different domains.I dont have admin access to the server as well as my chrome browser.Is there any other solution instead of using nodeJs?

Comment: Not really. there are cors proxy services out there where you can make the request through their server which basically does the same thing you would do on the server side in node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-request-origin-cor/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc) for chrome

in your API please add this code (if required)

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Ensure that the above plugin is enabled before making the request

Comment: I don't have admin access to my chrome browser,so cannot add plugin.

Answer (score 1):

use the chrome plugin

***CORS***

and switch on the "enable cross-origin resource sharing"